# Firefox Redirects on google.com, google.ca Unless Firebug is Open

Tags: firefox, redirection

On my mom's laptop, after entering google.ca or google.com, Firefox brings up her university's login page (not a fake. Has signed certificates and URL is legitimate) instead. She's at home, and not at school.

We've tried restarting Firefox, restarting the laptop, clearing the cache, clearing the offline content. Firefox is at the latest version. Google Chrome works fine though. `HOSTS` hasn't been touched. Setting proxy on Firefox to "no proxy", "auto detect for network", "use system" changes nothing. System doesn't have a proxy set either.

Weird thing is, those URLs don't get redirected if I enter them after bringing up Firebug with F12 or Inspect Element. The network tab actually shows the requests made, and everything goes to Google. When I close it, it starts redirecting again.

We also tried searching on Google after opening Firebug, closing Firebug, clicking on a result, and nothing gets redirected. Other sites don't seem to get redirected either if I enter their URLs without Firebug open.

This started happening today.

Comment: Have you cleared the cache (`Ctrl-Shift-Del`)?

Comment: Yes. Forgot to add that

Comment: Sounds odd.  Almost like someone messed with the host file.  

Quoting from WIKIPEDIA: "The hosts file is a computer file used by an operating system to map hostnames to IP addresses. The hosts file is a plain text file, and is conventionally named hosts. "

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

You may want to look inside of that to see if it was altered.  And you may want to scan for malware and/or spyware on your system.

Comment: Oh yeah, checked that too. I'll add it. It hasn't been touched. Nothing but comments :\